# Database design for: Very hierarchical data; off-server subset caching for processing; small to moderate size; (complete beginner)

Tags: sql, database

I found myself with a project (very relaxed, little to none consequences on failure) that I think a database of some sort is required to solve. The problem is, that while I'm still quite inexperienced in general, I've never touched any database beyond the tutorials I could dig up with Google and setting up your average home-cloud. I got myself stuck on not knowing what I do not know.

That's about the situation:

Several hundred different automated test-systems will write little amounts of data over a slow network into a database frequently. Few users, will then get large subsets of that data from the database over a slow network infrequently. The data will then be processed, which will require a large amount of reads, very high performance at this point is desired.

This will be the data (in order of magnitudes):

- 1000 products containing
- 10 variants containing
- 100 batches containing
- 100 objects containing
- 10 test-systems containing
- 100 test-steps containing
- 10 entries

It is basically a labeled B-tree with the test-steps as leave-nodes (since their format has been standardized).

A batch will always belong to one variant, a object will always belong to the same variant (but possibly multiple batches), and a variant will always belong to one product. There are hundreds of thousands of different test-steps.

Possible queries will try to get (e.g.):

- Everything from a batch (optional: and the value of an entry within a range)
- Everything from a variant
- All test-steps of the type X and Y from a test-system with the name Z

As far as I can tell rows, hundreds of thousands columns wide (containing everything described above), do not seem like a good idea and neither do about a trillion rows (and the middle ground between the two still seems quite extreme).

I'd really like to leverage the hierarchical nature of the data, but all I found on e.g. something like nested databases is, that they're simply not a thing.

It'd be nice if you could help me with:

1. What to search for
2. What'd be a good approach to structure and store this data
3. Some place I can learn about avoiding the SQL horror stories even I've found plenty of
4. If there is a great way / best practice I should know of of transmitting the queried data and caching it locally for processing

Thank you and have a lovely day

Andreas

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take a minute to read [tour] and [ask].  This question covers *a lot* of territory and is probably not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for "database normalization".
2. A normalized relational database is a fine structure.
3. If you want to avoid the horrors of SQL, you could also try a No-SQL [Document-oriented Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), like MongoDB. I actually prefer this kind of database in a great many scenarios.
4. The database will cache your query results, and of course, whichever tool you use to query the database will cache the data in the tool's memory (or it will cache at least a subset of the query results if the number of results is very large). You can also write your results to a file. There are many ways to "cache", and they are all useful in different situations.